# Why does IE still save and update files in the temp folder when caching is off?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-cache

In IE I changed the cache setting to

> "Every time I visit the web page"

.

However, I noticed in the directory

> \Local Settings\Temporary Internet
>   Files

that the files are still being stored in here and updated each time the page is called.

Is caching still on?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the words above this setting are "Check for newer versions of stored pages, which implies:
and

1. The pages is already in your cache a
2. It is just *checking* for a new version

So if the page hasn't changed, it will just display the cached version and not use up your bandwidth to download it again. If it has changed then it also updates the cache.

If you want to not have a cache, then you need to reduce the "Disk space to use" value.

Comment: thanks, seems the disk space to use will not go below 8?

Comment: Probably because of the index file or your homepage or something like that. Software tends to get in a tangle when caches don't exist at all.